# Date overlapping: generalized way to split the dates to get the overlapping interval?

Tags: excel, vba, algorithm, date, data-structures

Supose we have two date intervals:

```
A-------------B
       C-------------------------D
```

Where `A` and `C` are the begining dates, and `B` and `D` are the ending dates of the date intervals `AB` and `CD`.

I found that if `(B+D)>=(A+C)` we have date overlapping. But if `(B+D)<(A+C)`, we do not have date overlapping.

What I was looking for, but with no sucess, it to figure out a generalized algorithm that return me the split set of the the date interval `AB`. In the case above, the split set of `AB` would be:

```
A----------(C-1) 'I mean, begining date of interval CD diminished by one day
C----------B     'The actual date overlapping
```

I am not looking for a algorithm that test every possible case, but a generalized algorithm that apply to any case.

Is this algorithm exist? I really apreciate any help!!!

The all cases I can figure out are (but I am not sure that are others):

```
A---------------B
    C--------------------D

             A---------------B
C--------------------D

A---------------B
    C------D

    A------B
C---------------D

A---------------B
C---------------D

      A--------B
C--------------D

A--------------B
     C---------D

A--------------B
C-------D

A-------B
C--------------D
```

**EDIT**

Based on brilliant chosen answer by Gary's Student, I was able to figure out my needed function, as follows. I do not need to know which one of the intervals inside the split set of resulting invervals is the overlaping one, but with some changes in the function this is easily acomplished.

```
Sub Test()
arr = fSplitOverlap( _
DateSerial(2020, 3, 1), DateSerial(2020, 3, 31), _
DateSerial(2020, 3, 1), DateSerial(2020, 3, 10))
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) Step 2
    Debug.Print arr(i), arr(i + 1)
Next i
End Sub


Function fSplitOverlap(ByVal Di1 As Date, ByVal Df1 As Date, _
ByVal Di2 As Date, ByVal Df2 As Date) As Variant

Dim arr() As Date

Dim DiOver As Date, DfOver As Date
Dim HaveFirsDisjoint1 As Boolean: HaveFirsDisjoint1 = False
DiOver = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Di1, Di2)
DfOver = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Df1, Df2)

'TEST OVERLAP
If DateDiff("d", DiOver, DfOver) >= 0 Then

    'TEST FIRST POSSIBLE DISJOINT INVERVAL
    If DateDiff("d", Di1, DateAdd("d", -1, DiOver)) >= 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve arr(1 To 4)
        arr(1) = Di1
        arr(2) = DateAdd("d", -1, DiOver)
        arr(3) = DiOver
        arr(4) = DfOver
        HaveFirsDisjoint1 = True
    End If

    'TEST SECOND POSSIBLE DISJOINT INVERVAL
    If DateDiff("d", DateAdd("d", 1, DfOver), Df1) >= 0 Then
        If HaveFirsDisjoint1 = True Then
            ReDim Preserve arr(1 To 6)
            arr(1) = Di1
            arr(2) = DateAdd("d", -1, DiOver)
            arr(3) = DiOver
            arr(4) = DfOver
            arr(5) = DateAdd("d", 1, DfOver)
            arr(6) = Df1
        Else
            ReDim Preserve arr(1 To 4)
            arr(1) = DiOver
            arr(2) = DfOver
            arr(3) = DateAdd("d", 1, DfOver)
            arr(4) = Df1
        End If
    End If

End If

fSplitOverlap = arr

End Function
```

Comment: You say you don't want to test "every possible case" but you need to handle "any case".  What's the difference?

Comment: Hello @TimWilliams! I don't know how to express myself better in english, but I was looking for a generalized reasoning, provided by the choosen answer, instead of checking one by one each possible case that I listed, and the possible others cases not listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly from your pictures, if **A>D** or **C>B** then the regions are disjoint

Otherwise the overlap would be `MIN(B,D) - MAX(A,C) + 1`

So in VBA:

```
Sub Overlap()
    Dim A As Date, B As Date, C As Date, D As Date

    A = DateValue("1/11/2020")
    B = DateValue("1/20/2020")
    C = DateValue("1/15/2020")
    D = DateValue("2/13/2020")

    If A > D Or C > B Then
        MsgBox "no overlap"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        MsgBox .Min(B, D) - .Max(A, C) + 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Here the overlap is:

1. 1/15
2. 1/16
3. 1/17
4. 1/18
5. 1/19
6. 1/20

Comment: Thank you very much for showing us the generalized reasoning about overlapping date intervals!! I edited my text based on your answer.